# How to use linebreaks in a textbox?

Tags: php, xhtml, textarea, line-breaks

I am saving text from a textarea in the database and display it in another textarea. 
The linebreaks are displayed as \n which should be right, but the textarea is displaying 
them instead of doing the breaks! How can I fix this?

Comment: are you escaping and unescaping when storing and retrieving in and from database?

Answer (score 2):

You need to send a literal line break, not an escape sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you David,

this worked...

`str_replace('\n', "&amp;#10;", $text);`